# Remove an element from a separated list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given a list of elements separated by commas, how do I remove one element and the relevant separator, in a generic way, with jQuery or JS?

Example:

```
<div id="parent"><span name="one">one</span>,<span name="two">two</span>,
<span name="three">three</span>,<span name="four">four</span></div>
```

Result of `$("#parent").takeout("two")` would be:

```
<div id="parent"><span name="one">one</span>,
<span name="three">three</span>,<span name="four">four</span></div>
```

Now, result of `$("#parent").takeout("one")` would be:

```
<div id="parent"><span name="three">three</span>,<span name="four">four</span></div>
```

And, result of `$("#parent").takeout("four")` would be:

```
<div id="parent"><span name="three">three</span></div>
```

I would like something generic, that would work with any number of elements.

The reverse notation (starting with span name) would also work.

Answer (score 2):

```
var name = 'one';
var $el = $('#parent > span[name="'+name+'"]')[0];
if($el.nextSibling !== null){
    $el.nextSibling.remove();
} else {
    if($el.previousSibling !== null)
        $el.previousSibling.remove();
}
$el.remove();
```

Does this work?

Comment: This seperator means that it is only plain text ? Or are you actually using the DOM ?

Comment: No, as it does not remove the relevant separators (comma).

Comment: The separators are plain text (not surrounded by DOM element)

Comment: @javiexin this solution should now fully work for you

Comment: Great solution that sticks to only using the DOM! I should point out that this might not work if there is whitespace in the HTML. For instance a newline after the last `<span>` might be mistaken for `nextSibling` and removed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not very pretty, but it works:

```
jQuery.prototype.takeout = function(id) {

    //Remove the span.
    jQuery("[name=" + id + "]", this).remove();

    //Save the HTML code of the parent.
    var code = this.html();

    //Remove any leading commas.
    code = code.replace(/(^\s*),/, "$1");

    //Remove any ending commas.
    code = code.replace(/,(\s*)$/, "$1")

    //Remove any double commas.
    code = code.replace(/,(\s*),/, ",$1")

    //Set the HTML.
    this.html(code);

    //Enable chaining.
    return this;

};
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9fr4oth/1/).

Comment: Thanks, closer to the use pattern I wanted but cannot be concatenated: `$("#parent").takeout("four").takeout("two");` does not work as expected.

Comment: Didn't think about that. Fixed it now, all you have to do is to return `this` at the end. I would say that the method @Oskar uses is better if it works, since it sticks to the DOM and does not rely on doing regex on bare HTML code.

Comment: Perfect use pattern, and works.  I agree the other method is more DOM oriented.